# Adding axes to figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, subfloats, overpic

I need to add axes to a bunch of figures in my document, I'm trying with `tikz` but maybe there's an easier and more elegant way to do it (looking at you, `overpic`)?
The result I'm trying to achieve is not like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316488/182889), I need the axes to have the arrows as well.

I got some MWE working, but the axes are **vertically** misaligned (they should be *outside* of the picture). I've tryed adding `\vspace`s but they don't seem to work as I'd like.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**MWE**:

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \vspace{-0.6cm}
        \centering
        \subfloat[]{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0.5,0) node[right]{\footnotesize\(y\)};
            \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,0.5) node[above]{\footnotesize\(x\)};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \hspace{-1cm}
            \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}}
        \quad
        \subfloat[]{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0.5,0) node[right]{\footnotesize\(y\)};
            \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,0.5) node[above]{\footnotesize\(x\)};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \hspace{-1cm}
            \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}}
        \\
        \subfloat[]{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}}
            \hspace{-0.9cm}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw [->] (0,0) -- (-0.5,0) node[left]{\footnotesize\(y\)};
            \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,0.5) node[above]{\footnotesize\(x\)};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \quad
        \subfloat[]{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}
            \hspace{-0.9cm}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw [->] (0,0) -- (-0.5,0) node[left]{\footnotesize\(y\)};
            \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,0.5) node[above]{\footnotesize\(x\)};
            \end{tikzpicture}}
        \caption{Foo}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT** I would like the axes to be something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use the heavy `tikz` weapons, picture mode is sufficient to draw a few arrows:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \vspace{-0.6cm}
        \centering
        \subfloat[]{%
            \setlength{\unitlength}{\textwidth}
            \begin{picture}(.45,0.1)
                        \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}}
                        \put(.46,-.01){\vector(-1,0){.07}}
                        \put(.46,-.01){\vector(0,1){.05}}
                        \put(.453,.045){x}
                        \put(.373,-.014){y}
            \end{picture}
        }
        \caption{Foo}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Second approach with the heavy tikz weapons:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \vspace{-0.6cm}
        \centering
        \subfloat[]{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}};
            \draw [->] (image.south west) -- ++(0.5,0) node[right]{\footnotesize\textit{y}};
            \draw [->] (image.south west) -- ++(0,0.5) node[above]{\footnotesize\textit{x}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Off-topic: I would not use `[h!]` as floating specifier, this is almost always a guarantee for bad image placement

Comment: I need the axes to be lower, both outside of the picture

Comment: @Superuser27 You can move the arrows wherever you want

Comment: @Superuser27 Can you make a sketch where you want your axis to be?

Comment: So for the labels (`\put(.545,.07){x} \put(.46,.007){y}`) I just have to try around with the numbers until they are in the right position? Is there no easier way to position them relative to the picture maybe? Or just add labels to the `vector`s like with tikz?

Comment: @Superuser27 If you want sophisticated commands for automatic label placement, use tikz

Comment: I edited the question with what I would like to achieve. I have been trying to use tikz, that's also in the question :)

Comment: @Superuser27 I added a second solution with tikz

Comment: the `tikz` code is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much

Comment: Is there a way to distance the axes a tiny bit more from the picture in the `tikz` solution? The top of the "y" letter is pretty darn close to the image and I'd like to give it a bit of space if possible.

Comment: @Superuser27 Sure, you can change the `inner sep`. For example `\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=10pt]`

Comment: @Superuser27 You're welcome!

Comment: Actually what I was looking for is given by `\node (image) at (0,0) [inner sep=20pt]{\includegraphics.....}` But I anyways got there thanks to you :D (I only needed distance between figure and axes, not from axes and their labels as well)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<test,echo=F,fig.cap="Axis with background image and more.">>=
library(png)
ima <- readPNG("/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-a.png")
plot(1:2, type='n', xlab="x", ylab="y",xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,7.5),axes=F)
lim <- par()
u <- par("usr") 
rasterImage(ima, u[1]+.5, u[3]+.5, u[2]-.5, u[4]-.5)
arrows(u[1], u[3], u[2], u[3], code = 2, xpd = TRUE) 
arrows(u[1], u[3], u[1], u[4], code = 2, xpd = TRUE)
lines(c(1, 1.2, 1.35,4.5, 6, 8.3, 9.5), c(.6, 1.3, 0.9,2.7, 0.6, 4.7, 7.0), lwd=5, col="blue")
@
\end{document}
```

Of course, this need `R` and `knitr` to be compiled.

If you need only a little axis:

[image: mwe2]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<test,echo=F,fig.cap="Axis with background image and more.">>=
library(png)
ima <- readPNG("/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-a.png")
plot(1:2, type='n', xlab="", ylab="",xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,7.5),axes=F)
lim <- par()
u <- par("usr") 
rasterImage(ima, u[1]+.5, u[3]+.5, u[2]-.5, u[4]-.5)
arrows(u[1], u[3], u[2]/3, u[3], code = 2, xpd = TRUE) 
arrows(u[1], u[3], u[1], u[4]/3, code = 2, xpd = TRUE)
axis(1, at=u[2]/6, tck=0, labels="x") 
axis(2, at=u[4]/6, tck=0, labels="y") 
lines(c(1, 1.2, 1.35,4.5, 6, 8.3, 9.5), c(.6, 1.3, 0.9,2.7, 0.6, 4.7, 7.0), lwd=5, col="blue")
@
\end{document}
```

Comment: What code is this? :D never seen it... Actually I don't need to plot anything on the figure, I just need the axes.

Comment: @Superuser27 It is R code embedded in a LateX file (.Rnw) , that `knitr` (a R package)  export to a true/pure LateX file (.tex)  that can be compiled as usual . With R (free) and RStudio editor (free)  installed, all the process is simply push  the "Compile PDF" button.  With respect to the unwanted blue line, simply remove the  row `lines(c(1, ....`